# How to enable HTML in Popover or Tooltip in GWTBootstrap3?

Tags: java, twitter-bootstrap-3, gwtbootstrap3

I need to write some text within a Popover in bold. I am using GWTBootstrap3.

```
<g:FlowPanel addStyleNames="col-md-8">
                <b:Popover title="Enable CheckBox" content="text texttobebold" placement="RIGHT">   
                    <b:InlineCheckBox ui:field="onlineCheckbox" />
                </b:Popover >
            </g:FlowPanel>
```

So, I want to make some text in content written in bold. In normal bootstrap you can use data-html="true" to enable html and for instance use < strong >, but in gwtbootstrap3 it doesn't work and I get an error "use of < is not allowed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add the attribute `isHtml` to true:

```
<b:Popover  isHtml="true" trigger="HOVER">
```

:)