# Add image as an attribute value in popover(solved)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I am trying to show an image in the popover,

after i created an element i add attributes to show an popover.

```
var item = document.createElement('div');

var att2 = document.createAttribute("data-toggle");
var att3 = document.createAttribute("title");
var att4 = document.createAttribute("data-content");
var att5 = document.createAttribute("data-placement");

att4.value = "<img src ='blablabla.png' />;"
att3.value = itemname;
att2.value = "popover";
att5.value = "top"

item.setAttributeNode(att5);
item.setAttributeNode(att2);
item.setAttributeNode(att3);
item.setAttributeNode(att4);
```

any idea ? the output in the popover content is `<img src ='blablabla.png' />;`

SOLUTION
just add html:true into

```
 $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({html:true,trigger:"hover",container: 'body'});
```

Comment: you want to add an i image to the popover ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML inside Twitter Bootstrap popover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202762/html-inside-twitter-bootstrap-popover)

Comment: @g33k yes, but it doesnt explain why my method does not work.

Comment: Please move your solution to its own answer, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addImg(theDiv,theImg) {
  var element  = document.createElement("img");
  element.src = theImg;
  document.getElementById(theDiv).appendChild(element);
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv" onclick="addImg('myDiv','https://media1.popsugar-assets.com/files/thumbor/7NnYpYvDfxr_HYUpa4tySashCM8/fit-in/1024x1024/filters:format_auto-!!-:strip_icc-!!-/2017/03/17/915/n/1922398/40d6ad1840bc51bf_GettyImages-89938282/i/1997.jpg')">
Click me to append image
</div>
```

Is this kinda what you're after? Hard to tell from your explanation.