# Bootstrap popover not showing html content when trigger is set to manual

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-popover

searched for some time and didn't find an answer.
I want the popover to have html content, to open on hover and be clickable. But if I set the trigger to 'manual', then the button is not displayed. Do I set the trigger to hover, then the popover is not clickable. How can I fix that?
Here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wve4zuay/19/)

```
$(document).popover({ 
trigger: 'manual', 
sanitize: false, 
html: true, 
animation: true, 
selector: '.myHover', 
container: '#bootstrap-container'})

.on('mouseenter', '.myHover', function () { 
const _this = this; 
$(this).popover("show"); 
$(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () { 
    $(_this).popover("hide"); }); })
.on('mouseleave', '.myHover', function () { 
    const _this = this; 
  setTimeout(function () { 
  if (!$('.popover:hover').length) { 
    $(_this).popover('hide'); } }, 
    300); 
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML inside Twitter Bootstrap popover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202762/html-inside-twitter-bootstrap-popover)